# Custom merge function is not being called after updating field with cache.modify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have written a custom merge function for the field `products` on type `Session`. It seems the merge function is only being called when I initialise the object `Session:1` with its `products`, and not when I update `products` later using `cache.modify`.

My merge function:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8081/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Session: {
        fields: {
          products: {
            merge (existing, incoming) {
              // this is only being called on useQuery(HydrateSession), not useMutation(UpsertProduct)
              console.log('existing', JSON.stringify(existing, null, 2))
              console.log('incoming', JSON.stringify(incoming, null, 2))
              // remove duplicates when latestProduct has the same id as an existing product — [..., latestProduct]
              if (incoming.filter(p => p.id === incoming[incoming.length - 1].id).length > 1) return existing
              return incoming
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Initialisation of `Session`:

```
const HydrateSession = gql`
  query {
    session {
      id
      products {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`

...

useQuery(HydrateSession)
```

Updating `products` later using `cache.modify`:

```
const UpsertProduct = gql`
  mutation UpsertProduct($product: ProductInput!) {
    upsertProduct(product: $product) {
      id
    }
  }
`

...

const [upsertProductMutation] = useMutation(UpsertProduct)

const onClick = async () => {
  await upsertProductMutation({
    variables: {
      product: {
        id: 2
      }
    },
    update: (cache, mutationResult) => {
      cache.modify({
        id: 'Session:1',
        fields: {
          products: previous => [...previous, mutationResult.data.upsertProduct]
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I have a full working example here https://github.com/jsindos/apollo-play, run `npm i` and then start two separate processes with `npm start` and `npm serve`. After clicking the button triggering the mutation, the merge function is not run (as seen by the absence of `console.log` statements in the console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `modify` circumvents any merge functions you've defined, which means that fields are always overwritten with exactly the values you specify.

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify

Reading documentation is a good thing.